# Is Javascript array sort asynchronous?

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting, asynchronous

Is the Javascript Array.sort function asynchronous? I wouldn't think so, but when I run the following code, it sure seems to be:

```
$('#alphabetical-order').data('sort-column', 'FileAlpha');
$('#first-numeric-order').data('sort-column', 'FileFirstNumeric');
$('#last-numeric-order').data('sort-column', 'FileLastNumeric');
$('#alphabetical-order, #first-numeric-order, #last-numeric-order').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.data('compare-function', function(row1, row2) {
        console.log('column = ' + $this.data('sort-column')); // >> DEBUG 1
        compareRowsBasedOnColumn(row1, row2, $this.data('sort-column'));
    });
}).click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $content = $('table.sheetlist-content tr.content');
    $content.sort($this.data('compare-function'));
    console.log('$content.sort complete'); // >> DEBUG 2
    $table_body = $('table.sheetlist-content tbody')
    $table_body.html('');

    for (i=0; i<$content.length; ++i) {
        $table_body.append($content[i]);
    }
    saveAll(); // which POSTs to our server
});
```

(I can provide compareRowsBasedOnColumn if needed, but it's pretty much what the name says.)

Running in Firefox with the Firebug debugger, I see the POST from my `saveAll` in the console **before** the `DEBUG 2` above, interspersed with the `DEBUG 1`s, and I don't get my content effectively resorted. `DEBUG 1` is giving me the results I'd expect.

Offhand, this makes sense only the Javascript Array.sort function is asynchronous.

If, indeed, it is asynchronous, can anyone suggest a good way to rewrite this, short of writing my own sort (I'd really rather stick with theirs, if only for clarity).

Comment: No. It is not asynchronous.

Comment: *"I see the POST from my saveAll in the console before the DEBUG 2 above"* I don't understand what `saveAll()` has to do with `DEBUG 1`. What do you mean by *"I see the POST..."*?

Comment: Phrogz: as I say, that was always my understanding, but can you see any way to account for what I'm seeing in Firebug? Or the fact that it isn't writing back the changed table order?

Comment: Cookie monster: Each of those writes to the console, and can be viewed in the console pane of Firebug. (POSTs show up in the console.)

Comment: The relevant HTML (we have no data) and any functions required to run the given code. If you can create a jsfiddle to demonstrate the problem, that would be most useful.

Comment: @JoeMabel: So your confusion is that the POST request you're presumably making is displayed before the `console.log()`s? If so, I'd imagine that Firebug simply gives priority to displaying XHR requests.

Comment: Nigel: if no one can work it out in a day or so by eyeballing, I'll do that, but it would require table content, the substance of several other functions, and some sort of simulation of saveAll, because we certainly don't want something here that actually posts to a server.

Comment: Cookie: but also the re-sorted content isn't showing up in the table, which would be consistent with the for-loop running before the sort has returned.

Comment: saveAll() is fine, we will be able to see what it posts even if the address does not exist, or just echo the data that it would save to console instead. You don't need to give hundreds of lines of data, just enough to reproduce the problem.

Comment: FYI, jQuery doesn't *officially* have a `.sort()` method. Are you sure it actually mutates the jQuery object instead of returning a new, sorted object? EDIT: It does seem to mutate, though I'd be careful about using undocumented methods.

Comment: Nigel: there's a ton of such data, some of it quite unrelated to this. As I say, if no one can work this out by eyeballing in a day or so, I'll post a more complete, running example, but it that will require some coding, and also some testing on my end to make sure it reproduces the problem, since timing problems are not usually trivial to reproduce.

Comment: I doubt this question will last a day of eyeballing without enough code to reproduce the problem. http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Cookie monster: that's an interesting thought, and might be the key. My intent here is normal array sort. But maybe I need to use $.each() to extract them into an Array object rather than apply sort to the jQuery object. I'll try that. Thanks.

Comment: You may have missed it, but I updated my comment as it does seem to mutate.

Comment: ...oh wait, your `compare-function` doens't return a value! With no `return` statement, there can be no sorting taking place. Did you mean to do `return compareRowsBasedOnColumn(row1, row2, $this.data('sort-column'));`?

Comment: Ah, jQuery even has a .toArray().

Comment: OK. And it turns out that just the missing `return` does it. Treating the jQuery object as an Array here is fine.

Comment: So the sequence of console logs in FireBug was a misleading "artifact".

Comment: Consoles do funny things sometimes. It can be hard to rely on the ordering of their output at times. I'd still suggest not using that `.sort()` method since it's not an official part of the API. You can get identical behavior by doing `Array.prototype.sort.call(my_jquery_object, my_sort_function);`, and you won't need to wonder if the semantics or presence of jQuery's `.sort()` will change. Up to you though.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No. [`Array#sort`](http://es5.github.io/#x15.4.4.11) is guaranteed to be synchronous by the ECMAScript specification on which JavaScript is based on.

The algorithm is explicitly specified here:

> Let obj be the result of calling ToObject passing the this value as the argument.

Get the `this` value.

> Let len be the result of applying Uint32 to the result of calling the [[Get]] internal method of obj with argument "length".

Get the `.length` value.

> If comparefn is not undefined and is not a consistent comparison function for the elements of this array (see below), the behaviour of sort is implementation-defined.

Get the passed comparison function. If it is undefined, the implementation may do whatever it wants (in practice, it does lexical sort, however it has to be sync since we wait for it as we'll soon see).

> Perform an implementation-dependent sequence of calls to the [[Get]] , [[Put]], and [[Delete]] internal methods of obj and to SortCompare (described below), where the first argument for each call to [[Get]], [[Put]], or [[Delete]] is a nonnegative integer less than len and where the arguments for calls to SortCompare are results of previous calls to the [[Get]] internal method. The throw argument to the [[Put]] and [[Delete]] internal methods will be the value true. If obj is not sparse then [[Delete]] must not be called.
>
> Return obj.

So, it performs the operations in SortCompare. Which just compares them (a few lines below).

Note that the sort used is implementation defined (and actually varies across implementation), it is also not guaranteed to be stable.